# What's the Simplest Way to Convert a book from XeLaTex to Epub

Tags: conversion, books, book-design, html, epub

I have a 508-page book setup in LaTex. The book has 60+ images and uses custom fonts (the reason why I'm using XeLaTex). I use Overleaf and can easily spit out PDFs to create the paperback version of the book. I need to create an ePub version of the book for Kindle and digital platforms.

I looked at a lot of different threads and solutions (SimpleTeX4ht, Pandoc, TexStudio > HTML > Calibre, tex4ebook, etc). Nothing seems to work out-of-the-box for XeLaTex-compiled books.

What's the easiest/fastest/simplest way to get from LaTeX to ePub in my situation?

A big reason why I used LaTeX for layout is because it makes it easier to manage/update/reuse in different formats, so ideally I'd like to be able to use the same code base for everything.

Comment: `tex4ebook` (which is based on `tex4ht` ) allows all of the major engines (pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX) for compilation.

Comment: I'm a noob. Haven't been able to make it work. Ideally, I'm looking for something easier than command line. 

Comment: You will need to use commandline in every case. Use tex4ebook -x filename.tex to compile usin tex4ebook with xelatex. It can happen that not everything works out of the box, but it can be usually fixed.it would be best if you could add an example that shows what fails.

Comment: It seems this can't be done without a considerable will to learn new things on your part. On rather simple thing you could try is importing your file to lyx (https://wiki.lyx.org/GSoC/XHTMLePub) and then try from there. I cannot promise you anything except that there is a nice GUI which might make things easier …

Comment: imho as you managed to write a 500 page book you should stop call yourself a noob and tackle the task to learn to use the command line - it is not so difficult, basically it is only a plain black window where you type short words and then hit enter.

Comment: Haha. Fair point. :-) I did learn LaTeX in the past 8-10 days thanks in part to this community. :-) I'll try with @michal.h21's command and post if I run into issues. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to get it to run. :-) I got a lot of errors though. Any way to fix those? 

Just a sample:

```[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/ppxetex.def 43  Package pdfpages Error: The graphics package was loaded with driver
[ERROR]   htlatex: ? ?  Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 472.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ? ?  Emergency stop.
[FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command htlatex returned exit code 1 ```

Comment: I also run into compilation issues if I try to generate the html with ```make4ht``` instead of ```tex4ebook```:

```[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
[STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: main.tex
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ? 45  Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or
[ERROR]   htlatex: ? 45  Emergency stop.
[FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command htlatex returned exit code 1```

Comment: @egarbugli I don't get notifications if you don't my username in your comment. anyway, it is impossible to tell what is wrong without sample of your code. It can be caused by some package clash. From your second error mesage I see that you use Fontspec. In this case you need to call make4ht of tex4ebook with either -x (for XeLaTeX) or -l (for LuaLaTeX) option.